# Laravel 5 times out when rendering any view with data passed from controller

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

In my application, I've always been able to pass data to any view as one would normally do using `view('myView', compact('data'));`. As of today, any view I try to render this way times out. I'm getting the error `Maximum execution time of 120 seconds exceeded` in `Whoops!`. I tried increasing `php.ini` and `httpd.conf` timeout times but no cigar. It's really odd and it doesn't make sense to me because I've always been able to render my views almost instantly, even when retrieving 15k+ records from the database and passing them to the view like I've always done.

**My controller:**

```
use App\Product;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Session;

class HomeController extends Controller {


    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth');
    }

    public function index()
    {
        //the controller is normally like this
        //$products = Product::paginate(16);
        //return view('home', compact('products'));

        //I'm testing with these 2 lines below but no cigar.
        $product = Product::wherePid(303)->first();
        return view('test', compact('product'));
    }
}
```

**The test view I created:**

```
@extends('app')

@section('content')

    {{ $product->name }}

@stop
```

**My application view:**

```
@extends('app')

<pre>{{ var_dump(Session::all())}}</pre>

@section('content')
  <div class="row">
    @foreach($products as $product)
      <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3 col-lg-3 col-md-3">
        <?php
          if($product->img[7] == 'm' || $product->img[7] == 'M') echo "<div class='continenteIcon'></div>";
          else echo "<div class='jumboIcon'></div>";
        ?>
        <div class="thumbnail">
          <a href="products/{{$product->pid}}"><img src="{{$product->img}}" title="
            <?php
              if($product->dispname != '') echo $product->dispname;
              else echo $product->name;
            ?> ">
          </a>
          <div class="caption">
            <h4>
              <a style="text-decoration:none;" class="wordwrap" title="
                <?php
                  if($product->dispname != '')
                    echo $product->dispname;
                  else echo $product->name;
                ?>" href="products/{{$product->pid}}">
                <?php
                  if($product->dispname != '')
                    echo $product->dispname;
                  else echo $product->name;?>
              </a>
            </h4>
            <p>{{$product->brand}}</p>
            <span class="pull-right price">€{{$product->price}}</span>
            <br/>
            <span class="pull-right ppk">€{{round($product->pricekilo, 2)}} Kg, L ou Und</span>
          </div>
          <div class="ratings">
            <p class="pull-right">&nbsp;{{-- # review--}}</p>
            <p>
              <form method="post" action="add/{{$product->pid}}">
                <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{{ csrf_token() }}}" />
                <button title="Adicionar ao carrinho" type="submit" class="btn btn-success">
                 <i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i>
                </button>
              </form>
              <form method="post" action="products/related/{{$product->pid}}">
                <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{{ csrf_token() }}}" />
                <button title="Ver artigos semelhantes" style="position:relative; bottom:35px;" type="submit" class="btn btn-info pull-right">
                  <i class="fa fa-search"></i>
                 </button>
               </form>
             </p>
           </div>
         </div>
       </div>
       @endforeach
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        {!! $products->render() !!}
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="pull-right">
            * Preço por unidade, Litro ou Kilograma
        </div>
@stop


@section('scripts')

@stop
```

The problem **doesn't only happen in this view, but every single time I try to fecth someting from the database and pass it to the view** to render. I keep getting timeouts and I can't seem to fix it no matter what I do.

I am clueless why this is happening. It seems like it started out of the blue. I have no Idea what could be causing this issue.

Any help?

P.S.: I'm using Wamp.

EDIT: I forgot to add something that might be important:

Everything is up and running in Wamp. If I `dd()` out the query result and do not render the view

```
$products = Product::paginate(16);
dd($products);
//return view('home', compact('products'));
```

this is fast, as it always used to be. And by fast I mean it takes less than 1 second to retrieve everything I need. But if I render the view with

```
return view('home', compact('products'));
```

everything just stalls and I get a 500 (I checked with [Fiddler2](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler) and after the page stops loading, the request status is 500)

Comment: is your mysql running?

Comment: Yes, everything is up and running. I forgot to add and important detail: If I echo out the query result and do not render the view
    $products = Product::paginate(16);
    dd($products);
    //return view('home', compact('products'));
this is fast, as it always used to be. And by fast I mean it takes less than 1 second to retrieve everything I need. But if I render the view with
    return view('home', compact('products'));
everything just stalls and I get a 500 (I checked with Fiddler2[link](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler) and after the page stops loading, the request status is 500)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just sorted it out. The issue was in the following block of code in app.blade.php.

```
$size = Session::get('size');
...
<input type="text" value="'.Session::get($item).'">         
...
```

I was messing around with data from an existing session and everything was working fine. I assumed I was doing it right. I wasn't. Not by a chance :)

Assumption is the mother of all screw ups.

**Surrounded the whole block with** `if(Session::has('size')` **and everything is blazing fast and running smoothly as usual.**

Thanks @Pyton for pointing me out into the right direction and thanks everyone for your contribution.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you may be requesting too many records which may be using too much of your RAM. I would use the chunk command to help you with managing the amount you're requesting.

For example:

```
 User::chunk(200, function($users)
{
    foreach ($users as $user)
    {
        //
    }
});
```

Comment: If you look in his controller you'll see that he is currently only requesting 1 record.

Comment: Yes. Exactly what @BrokenBinary said. Also, this always worked before. Since yesterday, it doesn't anymore.

Answer (score 0):

First check logs.
Next try to `dd($product)`

Next if you try to render view with last 2 lines (getting first record) remove pagination from template. 
Clean template to minimum e.g.

```
@extends('app')

@section('content')
  <div class="row">
    @foreach($products as $product)

       @endforeach
      </div>
@stop
```

Comment: I'm gonna check those logs to see if I find anything, thanks. Meanwhile, I edited my question above adding more details related to your answer. Still no go.

Cleaning the template and doing as you stated doesn't help, unfortunately. I've tried it. The issue is definately related to rendering views. I'll dig into those logs to see if I find any clue.

Thank you